# How to identify more than one mode in this python pandas code on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, mode

I found a problem in completing this python pandas exercise. I am asked to write a pandas program to display most frequent value in a random series and replace everything else as 'Other' in the series.

I can't do it in a series but kind of OK in a dataframe. The code is shown below. My problem is: I can only select the value from the first index of the frequency counts list (i.e. `index[0]`), but it implies there is only one mode. What if there are more than one mode?

Grateful with your help. Thank you!

```
data19 = np.random.randint(46,50,size = 10)
df19 = pd.DataFrame(data19, columns = ["integer"])
print(df19)
freq19 = df19["integer"].value_counts()
print(freq19)
find_mode = df19["integer"] == freq19.index[0]  #What if there are more than one mode?
df19.loc[~find_mode, "integer"] = "Other"
print(df19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
mode = df19['integer'].mode()
df19.loc[~df19['integer'].isin(mode), 'integer'] = 'Other'
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! but I can't quite understand the meaning of the code. In the second line, I'm checking the integer column with the mode dataframe, but what is the use of second 'integer' of that line?

Comment: It's the second parameter of `loc`, i.e. the same as the `"integer"` in `df19.loc[~find_mode, "integer"] = "Other"`

Comment: See. Let me digest.